# How do I find out the date and time a specific offer was created?

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk, offer

The "Offer" object only contains a "last_modified_time" field, not when it actually was created, and no information about the transaction ID or ledger number.

Answer (score 0):

Horizon doesn't currently store the creation time and thus it doesn't offer it in the API responses.

I would recommend either or:

1. Creating an issue for it at https://github.com/stellar/go . Please indicate why the creation timestamp is critical for you.
2. Use Horizon's [ingestion library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stellar/go@v0.0.0-20211211173814-a047369b3e94/ingest) to extract the creation times yourself.